# How to insert data to DB using datagrid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to insert data to my SQL server database using a datagrid view.I added some data to the grid and need to commit them using a for loop.

```
Dim i, rowCount As Integer
rowCount = dgOrder.Rows.Count

For i = 0 To (rowCount - 1)
    objcon.DoExecute("INSERT INTO OrderMF (ItemType,ItemNm,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount,TotalValue,FreeItem)VALUES('" _
                        & dgOrder.Item(i, 1).Value & "','" _
                        & dgOrder.Item(i, 0).Value & "','" _
                        & txtOrdNo.Text & "','" _
                        & dgOrder.Item(i, 3).Value & "','" _
                        & dgOrder.Item(i, 2).Value & "','" _
                        & dgOrder.Item(i, 5).Value & "','" _
                        & dgOrder.Item(i, 4).Value & "','" _
                        & dgOrder.Item(i, 6).Value & "')")
    If objcon.m_Success = "0" Then
        MsgBox("Record Added Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ROBBIALAK")
        Call ClearFields1()
        cmdOrder.Enabled = False
    End If
Next
```

This is my code for the button click.But it dosen't work for me.it is getting a exception saying "Index was out of range.Must be non negative and less than the size of the collection,parameter name:index" .In this code dgorder is my datagridview name and I used a method call DoExecute to Execute the SQL String.please help me to get through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Against intuition, it is `.Item(columnIndex, rowIndex)` not `.Item(rowIndex, columnIndex)`. Luckily there is also `.Item(columnName, rowIndex)` and I advise you to use that, because that would increase readability a lot. So I think you should change

```
dgOrder.Item(i, 1).Value
```

to

```
dgOrder.Item("ItemType", i).Value
```

(if column name is "ItemType") and so on.

Also, it seems that you are trying to insert more values than there are columns specified

1. ItemType,
2. ItemNm,
3. UnitPrice,
4. Quantity,
5. Discount,
6. TotalValue,
7. FreeItem - **7 columns**:

   1. dgOrder.Item(i, 1).Value & "','" _
   2. & dgOrder.Item(i, 0).Value & "','" _
   3. & txtOrdNo.Text & "','" _
   4. & dgOrder.Item(i, 3).Value & "','" _
   5. & dgOrder.Item(i, 2).Value & "','" _
   6. & dgOrder.Item(i, 5).Value & "','" _
   7. & dgOrder.Item(i, 4).Value & "','" _
   8. & dgOrder.Item(i, 6).Value & "' - **8 values**